# How to disable line buffering of input in xterm from program?

Tags: c, input, buffering, xterm

Ie, how to get keystrokes send directly to my program without waiting for the user to press enter.  Basicly I'm trying get something like curses's `cbreak()` call.  (But I can't use curses due a couple of bugs/misfeatures that I haven't been able to work around.)  This seems like something that should just be a trival escape sequence, but I haven't been able find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookup `termios` and the `tcsetattr` function.

Comment: In particular, canonical mode has line-buffering and editing.  OP may be looking for that, and/or other flags to disable between cooked and raw mode.

Comment: <headdesk> Thanks (Still can't figure out why this isnt a escape.)

Comment: The buffering does not take place in the terminal. It takes place in the kernel's tty driver.

Comment: ...huh, freaking stream buffers.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this called the "raw mode"? If so, [this](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~holzmann/C/system/ttyraw.c) might help you.